# I have a Schengen visa which is valid till 20th Nov 2018. Can I apply for another Schengen visa for the same period?

Tags: schengen

I am an Indian national, and I have secured a Schengen visa for my travel to Germany which starts on 17th September 2018 and ends on 5th November 2018.

The visa is a type-C multiple-entry visa, which is valid from 17th September 2018 to 20th November 2018, for a period of 50 days.

I want to visit a tech conference which takes place in Lisbon, Portugal, between 5 and 7 November 2018 and also watch a Champions League match on 8 November 2018.

My problem is I exhaust my 50 days if I stay in Germany from 17th September 2018 to 5th November 2018. I will have to leave the Schengen area on 5th November.

My question is:

Can I apply for a Portugal visa for 5th November to 8th November, even if I already have a Schengen visa valid till 20th November (which expires on 5th November as I deplete my 50 days)?

Also, it is possible to apply for this visa when I am already in Germany?

Comment: If you plan to spend 50 days in Germany, and your visa is of limited duration, how would you go from Germany to Portugal for 5 extra days and it not appear that you've overstayed? You can get back to back visas, but generally could not apply for the Portuguese visa while in Germany. You could do the Portuguese trip, but why not leave Schengen and return?

Comment: @Giorgio I am asking if it’s possible to extend the Visa or apply for a new Portuguese Visa even if I have a Schengen Visa. However I’m really thinking hard for applying for a UK Visa and visit UK for five days and enter Schengen area again and still use my 50 days here.